# iOS: Keeping UIToolBar on top during segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UIViewController` which segues (push) to another `UIViewController`. The first controller contains a nicely laid out `UIToolBar` menu and I want this to persist over the secondary `UIViewController` (and another other ones I push on the navigation stack).

Is this possible?

Comment: Where do you have this tool bar? Is it at the top of your view, right under the navigation bar, or at the bottom?

Comment: Bottom of the screen. Needs to persist application-wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a container view in a storyboard, or using the custom container view controller api in code. In the storyboard, you can add your tool bar to a view controller, drag in a container view, and size it to take up the rest of the view. You will automatically get a view controller connected with an embed segue to the container view. Select it, and embed it in a navigation controller. You can use prepareForSegue (which will be called immediately after your main view controller - the one with the container view - is instantiated) to get a reference to the navigation controller (it will be the destinationViewController).